# Push object to array and if there any duplicate date, its merge that inherit object for same date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, loops, object

This is my main array used for the table

```
const [tableData,setTableData] = useState([]);
```

this is the object pushed from my form

```
{ date: "2022-08-07", selectedData: { somedata: 'somedata'} }
```

I want to push these objects to `tableData` array , If there are any duplicate `date` need to merge `selectedData` object,

I expect an array like below

```
[
    { date: "2022-08-07", selectedData: [{ somedata: 'somedata1'},{ somedata: 'somedata2'}] },
    { date: "2022-08-08", selectedData: [{ somedata: 'somedata'}] },
]
```

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: @David  
const pushSelectedObjectToArray = () => {
  setTableDataArray({ ...tableDataArray, selectedTableData });
  setTableDataArray(newArray);
  console.log(tableDataArray, 'newArray');
 };

Comment: I expand the array and try to push the data then merge the objects with same date

Comment: Aside from describing the expected outcome can you also include what code you have developed to get the expected outcome, and the trouble area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which does not require an additional pass in keying the entries by date. Since object keys do not technically have an order (even though most browsers honor it) in the ECMA spec, its probably better to keep everything as an array through the whole process.

```
   const pushTableData = (dataToPush) => {
      setTableDataArray(prevData => {
          const newData = [...prevData]
          const existingObjectIndex = prevData.findIndex(row => row.date === dataToPush.date)
          if (existingObjectIndex !== -1) {
              newData[existingObjectIndex] = {date: dataToPush.date, selectedData: [...prevData[existingObjectIndex].selectedData, dataToPush.selectedData]}
          } else {
              newData.push({data: dataToPush.date, selectedData: [dataToPush.selectedData])
          }

          return newData
      })
   }
```

Comment: I don't see you iterating over the data and merging the possible duplicate values, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. The iteration happens in `findIndex`. First it searches the array for the index of the matching item, then goes and uses that. If something is found, the index is != -1, and it then uses that to modify it.

Comment: Does this only work with one dup?

Comment: Correct. Though I'm guessing all data being added goes through this function and so it would be ok in that case. It could easily be modified to replace dupes, but I think he wont have them in the first place if using this. If he wants really strong guarantees he probs ought to change the data structure to one that guarantees it.

Comment: I think to handle the possibility of multiple dups, for example "x" is in the array of data three times, you can simply replace your ```existingObjectIndex``` with a
`const exists = Object.values(prevData).includes('x') || Object.values(newData).includes('x')` or something similar

Comment: The solution is reliant on having the index at hand though, so it can use it to modify the entry -- hence find index. Knowing it exists or not isnt quite enough by itself. I believe for it to work with dupes it would need to be modified to get all indexes (probably using a reduce) then be changed to loop over those indexes and modify all of them.

Comment: Well now that I think about it you can just simply to `const exists = Object.values(newData).includes('x')`

Comment: see `newData[existingObjectIndex]`

Comment: @AdamThomas thanks for your great solution, but in code always get existingObjectIndex = -1 , https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-http-eqo980

Comment: I checked you example, added some logging on `existingObjectIndex` and clicked the button twice. The first time it is -1, the second it is 0, which makes sense since the first time its not already in there and the second time its the first item in the array. It appears to be working correctly.

Comment: @AdamThomas its works, thanks, I learned a lot!

Comment: @Nekromenzer Would you mind marking as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the reduce function. First, you need to iterate on the dates and store them in an object with `date` keys. Then if you have added the `date`, you should add `selectedData` to it. Else, you should add the object with the `date` key. You can check the code here:

```js
const dates = [
  { date: "2022-08-07", selectedData: { somedata: 'somedata'} },
  { date: "2022-08-07", selectedData: { somedata: 'somedat2'} },
  { date: "2022-08-07", selectedData: { somedata: 'somedat3'} },
  { date: "2022-08-08", selectedData: { somedata: 'somedata'} },
  { date: "2022-08-08", selectedData: { somedata: 'somedata2'} },
  { date: "2022-08-10", selectedData: { somedata: 'somedata'} },
  { date: "2022-08-11", selectedData: { somedata: 'somedata'} },
]

const result = Object.values(dates.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  return {
    ...prev,
    [curr.date]: prev[curr.date] ? { ...prev[curr.date], selectedData: [...prev[curr.date].selectedData, curr.selectedData] } : { ...curr, selectedData: [curr.selectedData] }
  }
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should see whether `date` property of `selectedData` exists in any of `tableData`. Lets say your new object from form is called `newData`

```
setTableData((tableData) => {
  const cloned = [...tableData];

  for (let i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    if (newData.date === tableData[i].date) {
      cloned[i] = {
        ...cloned[i],
        selectedData: [...cloned[i].selectedData, newData.selectedData]
      };
      return cloned;
    }
  }

  return [...cloned, newData];
});
```

1. You can implement the logic you want inside or outside of `setTableData`.
2. Never mutate your state.

Comment: Looks like you went roughly the same way I did :). Note though I think you have an error here: `selectedData: [...cloned[i].selectedData, newData]` should be `selectedData: [...cloned[i].selectedData, ...newData.selectedData]`

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I did not see your answer when I was writing this one.

Comment: No worries. I just realised theres a problem with mine as well which is also in yours. Ive just corrected. For you, the final return to push `newData` if theres no match needs to modify `newData` such that the  `selectedData` is put in an array before adding.